# How can UploadiFive or Uploadify post to an array to a MVC controller instead of multiple posts

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, uploadify

I am trying to use uploadifive/uploadify to upload multiple files to a website. UploadiFive/Uploadify works, but it calls my controller multiple times. Once for each file uploaded. how could I change Uploadify/Uploadifive, so that it only calls the controller once with an array of the files uploaded.

I have this in my html view:

```
<div id="uploads"></div>
<input type="file" name="file_upload[]" id="file_upload" multiple/><br />
<a href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload')">Upload Files</a>
```

And here's my jQuery-code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {        
  $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
     'formData': { 'Id': $("input[name='Id']").val()},
     'queueSizeLimit': 10,
     //'queueID':'uploads',
     'fileObjName': 'file',
     'method': 'post',
     'auto': false,
     'multi':true,
     'buttonText': 'Upload Files',
     'dnd': false,
     'simuploadLimit': 10,
     'uploadScript': '/Project/UploadDoc',
     'onUploadComplete': function (file, data) {
         console.log(data);
     },
     'onFallback': function () {
         alert('HTML5 is not supported in this browser.');
     },
     'onClearQueue': function (queueItemCount) {
         alert(queueItemCount + ' file(s) were removed from the queue');
     },
     'onQueueComplete': function (queueData) {
      //   alert(queueData.uploadsSuccessful + ' files were successfully uploaded.');
       //  $('#file_upload').uploadifyCancel('*');
     },
       'onDestroy' : function() {
           alert('I am getting destroyed!');
     }  
  });        
});
```

Note I'm using MVC3 c# entity framework, the latest uploadify/Uploadifive and Javascript is up to the most recent version.